# when the function works the else statement is the one that executed

Tags: javascript, helper

Please Guys some Help Really  i stuck here why the else statement works rather than if statement

```
function add() {
  if (input.value !== "") {

    localStorage.setItem("name", input.value);

    results.innerHTML = `localStorage item <span class='green'>${input.value}</span> been added`;

    input.value = '';
  }
};
```

when the add() function add a value from the input i want to check if this value exists in the
`localStorage` but the else statement that is the one that works

```
function check() {
  if (input.value !== "") {

    if (localStorage.getItem(input.value)) {

        results.innerHTML = `Found item in Local Storage With Name ${input.value}`;

    } else {
        results.innerHTML = `No Local Storage with Name <span class='green'>${input.value}</span>`;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the html part and the variable declaration part how you get input value and when the add() function is execute ?

Comment: getItem('name') will fix it

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the item by its name. `localStorage.getItem(input.value)` should be `localStorage.getItem("name")`

Comment: That could be just a comment and a close vote